# c# transactions catching single/multiple return (field) from NonQuery on sql or firebird

Tags: c#, sql, transactions, firebird

I have this code that inserts data into multiple tables. My problem is how to catch multiple returns after an insert in the database and store it in a variable.

I will use the returned values to insert it in another table.

By the way `fbtransaction` is almost the same with SQL transaction. I just need to retrieve the values

- tbl_employee(table 1)
- empID  pk(auto inc)
- empMonitorID (auto inc)
- positionID fk
- first name
- last name

here is my code

```
using FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient;

DBconnection dbConString = new DBconnection(); //initialize connectDB with connection string
FbConnection dbConnect = new FbConnection(dbConString.getConnectionString()); // connect to database using connectdb
dbConnect.Open();
FbTransaction transaction = dbConnect.BeginTransaction(); // instantiate transaction
try
{

    FbCommand myCommand = new FbCommand(getQueryStrings(), dbConnect, transaction);

    string return_empid = myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()// have no idea how the return EmpID
    string return_empMonitorID = myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()// have no idea how to retrieve empMonitorID 

    FbCommand myCommand2 = new FbCommand(getQueryStrings(return_empid), dbConnect, transaction);//need to add return_empid to be insertted to the postion table
myCommand2.ExecuteNonQuery()


    transaction.Commit();
}
catch (Exception x)
{
    transaction.Rollback();
    MessageBox.Show("No Update has been made. Error (" +
    x.Message + ")");
 }
 finally
 {
     dbConnect.Close();
 }


private void getQueryStrings()
{
    return " insert into tbl_employee (positionID,first name,last name) values
    ('" + txtposiID + "','" + fname + "','" + lname + "' 
) returning empID,  empMonitorID ;" //this query returns emp id and emp monitor id
}
```

**UPDATE**:

I am trying to use this code but i can't seem to make it work. Can anyone correct me if this can work

```
string return_empid = = (string)myCommand.ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: What do you mean with _"catch multiple returns value"_?

Comment: as you can see at my insert statement the database will throw back or will return 2 id which are EMPid and empMonitorID. EmpID and Empmonitorid is database generated or auto incremented

Comment: Ah, I see, as far as I know you should execute it as a query (eg as you would a select), but I currently don't have access to visual studio so I can't check that.

Comment: Execute it by a select query again will be my last option if no one can answer my question. Such a waste of database feature if c#.net cannot handle an insert that returns multiple values or fields. It can save a lot of lines of code if somebody can answer it.

Comment: I think you misunderstood: you need to execute the `INSERT ... RETURNING ...` as if it is a select; the columns in the `RETURNING` clause will then be returned in a data reader and can be processed as if you selected them. So there is no need for a separate select.

Comment: BTW: I might be mistaken, and you may need to register two additional out parameters to the command and execute it as a non query. But as I said, I can't test this right now.

Comment: this is my reference in using insert return http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd21-insert.html. i found a code  string sample = (string)myCommand.ExecuteScalar(); but it returns a Blank string

Comment: here is another reference but i can't make it work is something am I missing http://www.sqlines.com/oracle-to-sql-server-cs-conversion/insert-returning-clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After days of frustration I finally found my answer on returning multiple values on insert.

Instead of using `ExecuteNonQuery()`, I used `ExecuteScalar()` as shown on my code below. I also added parameters to the command so that I can catch the specific rows in the return.

```
myCommand.Parameters.Add("empID", SqlDbType.BigInt).Direction =ParameterDirection.Output;
myCommand.Parameters.Add("empMonitorID ", SqlDbType.BigInt).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
myCommand.ExecuteScalar();
MessageBox.Show(myCommand.Parameters["empID"].Value.ToString());
MessageBox.Show(myCommand.Parameters["empMonitorID "].Value.ToString());
```

This code avoids an additional select query after the insert.

Comment: Also consider using parameters for the values you are inserting, your current code as shown in the question is open to sql injection

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is 2 years old but maybe this can help someone else. For Firebird, Use 'returning', and add a new FbParameter with an output direction, then ExecuteNonQuery then you can grab the value from the parameter and do whatever you like with it.

```
"insert into db (field1,field2) VALUES (@value1,@value2) returning id"
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value1",myvalue);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value2",myvalue);
cmd.Parameters.Add(new FbParameter { ParameterName = "RET_id", FbDbType = FbDbType.Integer, Direction = ParameterDirection.Output });
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
string myReturnid = cmd.Parameters["RET_id"].Value.ToString();
```

Answer (score -2):

you will need to put the inserts into a selectable stored procedure, then do `select from my_sp(val1, val2, ...)`

where the sp looks something like

```
declare procedure mysp (val1 integer, val2 integer) returning val8 integer, val9 integer

begin
insert into table1 ... returning into :val8;

insert into table2 ... returning into :val9;

suspend;

end
```

Comment: I don't have a problem on how return a value during insert on the database side. My problem is on how to catch the returning value from the database on the c#.net side.